# Flowplayer Secure Streaming "Stream not found"

Tags: security, streaming, video-streaming, flowplayer

My client wants his videos hidden and not having the possibility to be downloaded or copied (or at least to make it difficult to do).

I'm trying to use flowplayer secure streaming, but I cannot make it work!

I'm getting this error:

> 200, Stream not found, NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound, clip: '[Clip]
>   'secure/ad722768cfa6f10b51b7e317c8dd1ca4/1417957647/v.mp4"

It says the video was not found, but it's placed on **secure/v.mp4** as it should (right?)

**UPDATE1**

I forgot to mention that I have the required apache rewrite rule inside secure folder…

**secure/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /secure

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ video.php?h=$1&t=$2&v=$3

RewriteRule ^$ - [F]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+\.(flv|mp4)$ - [F]
```

**UPDATE2**

I did it! It was a dumb simple thing:

I was testing with easyphp webserver, and the url was localhost/v/index.html

I did a test moving all the content from /v folder to the root and it worked!

And now I learned in htaccess I need to put the full path on RewriteBase starting from the root, in my case I needed to set this:

```
RewriteBase /v/secure
```

The codes:

**index.html**

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="flowplayer-3.2.13.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $f("player", "flowplayer-3.2.18.swf", {
      plugins: {
        secure: {
          url: "flowplayer.securestreaming-3.2.9.swf",
          timestampUrl: "sectimestamp.php"
        }
      },
      clip: {
        baseUrl: "secure",
        url: "v.mp4",
        urlResolvers: "secure",
        scaling: "fit",
      }
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="player"></div>  
</body>
```

**sectimestamp.php**

```
<?php
echo time();
?>
```

**secure/video.php**

```
<?php
$hash = $_GET['h'];
$streamname = $_GET['v'];
$timestamp = $_GET['t'];
$current = time();
$token = 'sn983pjcnhupclavsnda';
$checkhash = md5($token . '/' . $streamname . $timestamp);

if (($current - $timestamp) <= 2 && ($checkhash == $hash)) {
  $fsize = filesize($streamname);
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $streamname . '"');
  if (strrchr($streamname, '.') == '.mp4') {
    header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
  } else {
    header('Content-Type: video/x-flv');
  }
  header('Content-Length: ' . $fsize);
  session_cache_limiter('nocache');
  header('Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT');
  header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
  header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
  header('Pragma: no-cache');
  $file = fopen($streamname, 'rb');
  print(fread($file, $fsize));
  fclose($file);
  exit;
} else {
  header('Location: /secure');
}
?>
```

I already tried this > [Flowplayer Secure Streaming with Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860868/flowplayer-secure-streaming-with-apache) but I also get the error above.

Does anyone use flowplayer secure streaming? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong, in htaccess you need to put the full path on RewriteBase starting from the root, in my case I needed to set this:

> RewriteBase /v/secure